# How to Stop ArcGIS API For JavaScript Drawing After Click on Map

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, toolbar

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know how I can stop drawing after adding the first point to the map?

as you can see I tried using the `toolbar.finishDrawing();`

but this is not stopping the drawing and adding new points on each click on mao

```
  $("#btnPoint").on("click", function () {
      toolbar = new Draw(map);
      toolbar.activate(Draw.POINT);
      map.hideZoomSlider();
      toolbar.on("draw-end", addToMap);

      function addToMap(evt) {
          var graphic = new Graphic(evt.geometry, config.symbolPointFlag);
          pGraphicsLayer.add(graphic);
      }
      toolbar.finishDrawing();
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knwing In your above code you're creating the toolbar every click , and also ataching the event + creating the addToMap function , which is a bad practice ...

So what you have to do is refactoring your code :

- create your toolbar , in the main code (outside event)
- decalre addToMap function outside the event
- change your the `toolbar.finishDrawing();` by `toolbar.deactivate();` as @Reza mentionned

please be informed that the toolbar.finishDrawing(); will not disable the drawing toolbar it will trigger the draw-end event which is usless in case o fpoint drawing , by example if you want to stop drawing of line or polygone at a some stage , just call this last and it'ill trigger the draw end , ( draw only line with three vertices by example )

Please See a [Demo Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/nkkyzvhy/) :

Whole code (in case of fiddle loss)

**HTML :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var dojoConfig = {
       async: true,
       parseOnLoad: true
   };
</script>
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" design="headline" splitters="false" id="DashboardContainer">
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" id="DashboardTop" region="top">
    <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="setStart" type="button">
      Set Starting Location
    </button>
    <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="setStop" type="button">
      Set Stopping Location
    </button>
    <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="clear" type="button">
      clear !
    </button>
    |
    <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="send" type="button">
      Send request
    </button>
  </div>
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" region="center" id="map" >
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
require(['esri/map', "esri/toolbars/draw", "dojo/on", 'dojo/parser', 'dojo/ready', 'dijit/registry', "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer", "esri/graphic", "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol", 'dijit/layout/BorderContainer', 'dijit/layout/ContentPane', ],
   function(Map, Draw, On, parser, ready, registry, GraphicsLayer, Graphic, SimpleMarkerSymbol, BorderContainer, ContentPane) {

  var map;
  var toolbar;
  var pGraphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer({
    id: "pGraphicsLayer"
  });
  var symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol();


  ready(function() {


    map = new Map("map", {
      basemap: "streets",
      center: [-90, 39],
      zoom: 9
    });

    map.on("load", function() {
      toolbar = new Draw(map);
      toolbar.on("draw-end", addToMap);
      map.addLayers([pGraphicsLayer]);
    });

    On(registry.byId("btnPoint"), "click", function(e) {
        toolbar.activate(Draw.POINT);
        map.disableMapNavigation();
    });

    On(registry.byId("clear"), "click", function(e) {
      pGraphicsLayer.clear();
    });


  });



  addToMap = function(evt) {

    toolbar.deactivate();
    map.enableMapNavigation();
    pGraphicsLayer.add(new Graphic(evt.geometry, symbol));
  };


});
```

**CSS :**

```
#DashboardContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#DashboardTop {
  height: 30px;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your addToMap function, add

```
toolbar.deactivate();
```

Delete the toolbar.finishDrawing(); where it is now.

Your code says once the drawing is complete, hit addToMap, thats where you need to deactivate your toolbar.